# Where does this extra space come from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

As seen in the picture(I also put the code in to try and make it a little easier). The website is scrolled sideways (which shouldn't happen) and the body is in the blue outline but there is extra scrollable space at the right hand side.

As you can also see in the css I can hide the "extra" space by using `overflow-x: hidden;` but it's not good enough because if I were to the use `float: right;` on another element, while using the `overflow-x: hidden;`, the `float: right;` element would be off the edge of the screen.

My question is where is this "extra" space coming from?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-width=1, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

</head>

<body>
<!--    <div id="navanchor"></div>Anchor to change nav size on scroll-->
        <div id="container">

            <nav id="nav">
                <img id ="logo" src="http://placehold.it/160x75" alt="Max's barbers logo.">

                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#prices">Prices</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul><!--menu-->
            </nav>

<!--slider-->
            <!--=============-->
<!--end slider-->
<!--            <div id="top"></div>Anchor for scroll to top button-->
    </div><!--container-->

<!--Scripts
=====================================================-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--Custom JS
=====================================================-->
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

<!--==============-->



</body>
</html>
```

& the CSS

```
/*      1 - Fonts
        2 - Site Wide Styles
            2a - Navigation
            2b - Scrollbar
            2c- Selection
        3 - Sections
        4 - Media Queries
==============================================================*/
/* 1 - fonts
==============================================================*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Raleway);
/*
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
*/
/* 2 - site wide styles
==============================================================*/
* {
    color: #75e7ff;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.43s cubic-bezier(0.35, 1.32, 0.49, 1.01);
    transition: all 0.43s cubic-bezier(0.35, 1.32, 0.49, 1.01);
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
/*    overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

body {
    background-color: #383838;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* 2a - Navigation
==============================================*/
nav {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 4.75em;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 5.25em;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
#menu li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}

/* 3 - Sections
==============================================================*/
/* 3a - Home
==============================================*/


/* 4 - Media Queries
==============================================================*/
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle please? https://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues causing this problem.  First,

```
nav {
    width: 100vw; /* remove this -- you don't need it! */
    ...
}
```

Second, as mentioned in the other answer,

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 0; /* changed from 5.25em */
}
```

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/0gLvog4q/1/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 5.25em;
}

nav {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 4.75em;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
```

just change the margin-right: 5.25em; to something fitting your requirements and remove the width of the nav.

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

nav {
    height: 4.75em;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
```

[a fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/0gLvog4q/2/)

Comment: This alone will not solve the problem -- it just pushes the nav links off the right side of the screen, which results in the page still scrolling horizontally.

Comment: there you go! just remove the nav width!

Answer (score 0):

remove this line in the css, just under `nav`

```
 width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the margin-right...

I would use the following

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

also remove the following for the width of the whole thing

```
width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think people understand the OP's set up and their question. If he removes `width: 100vw` (like so many people are saying) then the horizontal "bouncing" effect does not work any more and they are left with a static navigation menu.

The issue is the `nav` left and right padding but to just remove it wouldnt be the best result. Instead you would have to add a nested `DIV` just after the `NAV` and add the padding there. See this code:

HTML

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div class="box">
      <img id ="logo" src="http://placehold.it/160x75" alt="Max's barbers logo.">

      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#prices">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul><!--menu-->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Changed CSS

```
nav {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 4.75em;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.box {
    padding: 0 2em
}
```

[Here is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gLvog4q/3/). Hope that helps.