# Extra scroll space at the right of my webpage

Tags: html, css

I have some space to the right of my web page that I would like to get rid of.

I have checked to make sure I have no extra padding in my header. I have also checked multiple other similar problems on Stack Overflow including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812983/where-does-this-extra-space-come-from), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812983/where-does-this-extra-space-come-from), but they didn't provide an answer that worked for me. I have checked to see if I had any unnecessary margins or borders on my code, and I could not find any. I have also tried to change the overflow to hidden but have had no luck.

I have reduced the webpage to the small area that I have found to be causing the problem.

Here is my HTML:

```css
#h1 {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 60%;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  #back1 {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 127px;
    left: 59%;
    background: grey;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }

  #p1 {
    width: 490px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: 19%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
  }


  #back2 {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: 18%;
    background: grey;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .parallax { 
      background-image: url("https://pi.tedcdn.com/r/tedideas.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/featured_art_heal_forests.jpg");
      height: 500px; 
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
  }

  body {
    background: #223031;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right,#223031,#178d50); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top right,#223031,#178d50);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top right,#223031,#178d50);
    background: linear-gradient(top right, #223031, #178d50);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Test</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<h1 id="h1"><strong>Title Here</strong></h1>
<div id="back1"></div>

<p id="p1"> Duis platea risus dapibus convallis et dis luctus netus purus. Vel sed vulputate sollicitudin ac praesent imperdiet. Massa primis luctus conubia Curabitur ac. Molestie justo praesent at dolor taciti feugiat. Orci Pretium iaculis. Vehicula magnis proin. Dictumst habitant Adipiscing augue vivamus eget.
</p>
 <div id="back2"></div>

<div class="backgroundimg"></div>



<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anything and everything is appreciated. Thanks (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `#h1`. You have `width: 100%` set on it and then absolutely positioned. Remove the width. You don't actually need it anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I missed that (:   Will look out for this in the future

Comment: Glad I could help!